# What is the best was to rearrange a list of tuples based on their first element, to match a string?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, match

I have a list of tuples that looks like:

```
[(['A', 'E', 'J', 'M', 'S'],), (['E', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'A'],), (['F', 'B', 'F', 'C', 'C'],)]
```

or if it's easier, before I used zip() it looked like this:

```
[['A', 'E', 'J', 'M', 'S'],
['E', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'A'],
['F', 'B', 'F', 'C', 'C']]
```

I'm trying to re-order the top row so it reads J A M E S, and have the bottom rows follow. What is the best way to go about this. Thanks for any help.

The output i'm aiming for is

```
[['J', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'S'],
['D', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
['F', 'F', 'C', 'B', 'C']]
```

Comment: Are you doing this manually, or do you use some kind of algorithm to rearrange the first list?

Comment: What is the sorting criteria for the other two lists?

Comment: The other two lists just have to match up with their position in relation to the top list. The program as a whole is an encryption script, and the 2 lists after the JAMES list are used as a key.

Answer (score 2):

assuming you arrange the first row manually, make `a` a `numpy.ndarray`, and slice it with the manually chosen index array:

```
In [117]: a=np.array([['A', 'E', 'J', 'M', 'S'],
     ...: ['E', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'A'],
     ...: ['F', 'B', 'F', 'C', 'C']])

In [118]: idx=[2,0,3,1,4]  #index array

In [119]: a[:,idx]
Out[119]: 
array([['J', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'S'],
       ['D', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'A'],
       ['F', 'F', 'C', 'B', 'C']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary that contains keys like `'J'`, `'A'`, `'M'`, .. pointing to some numbers to get the desired order and then use this dictionary to sort the unzipped version(`zip(*..)`) of your list of lists.

```
>>> lis = [['A', 'E', 'J', 'M', 'S'],
['E', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'A'],
['F', 'B', 'F', 'C', 'C']]
>>> d = {'J':0, 'A':1, 'M':2, 'E':3, 'S':4}
>>> zip(*sorted(zip(*lis), key= lambda x: (d[x[0]])))
[('J', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'S'), ('D', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'A'), ('F', 'F', 'C', 'B', 'C')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to associate the data with your sort keys, sort, then extract the data in order. More or less DSU. In this case, zip is a quick way to 'cross' the matrix, so zip the tuples, do your sorting (however you want to do it... in the below, i used a fixed mapping since i don't know your sort criteria), zip the other way:

```
input = [['A', 'E', 'J', 'M', 'S'],
    ['E', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'A'],
    ['F', 'B', 'F', 'C', 'C']]

input_zip = zip(*input)
print input_zip
[('A', 'E', 'F'),
 ('E', 'C', 'B'),
 ('J', 'D', 'F'),
 ('M', 'A', 'C'),
 ('S', 'A', 'C')]

indices = [2,0,3,1,4]
output = [input_zip[x] for x in indices]
[('J', 'D', 'F'),
 ('A', 'E', 'F'),
 ('M', 'A', 'C'),
 ('E', 'C', 'B'),
 ('S', 'A', 'C')]

# Zip it the other way now.
output_zip = zip(*output)
[('J', 'A', 'M', 'E', 'S'),
 ('D', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'A'),
 ('F', 'F', 'C', 'B', 'C')]
```

hopefully that doesn't just answer the question, but explain the thinking behind it.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like what you want is to first order the data so that you have the corresponding element from each of your lists in a list of its owns so:

```
    input = [['A', 'E', 'J', 'M', 'S'],
            ['E', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'A'],
            ['F', 'B', 'F', 'C', 'C']]
    rearrangedlist = [[input[x][y] for x in range(len(input))] for y in range(len(input[0]))]

    # Gives rearrangedlist = [['A', 'E', 'F'],
                             ['E', 'C', 'B'],
                             ['J', 'D', 'F'],
                             ['M', 'A', 'C'],
                             ['S', 'A', 'C']]
```

then:

```
    correctorder = ['J','A','M','E','S']
    rearrangeddict = [dict((x[0],x[1:]) for x in rearrangedlist)]
    for lettertofind in correctorder:
        print rearrangeddict[lettertofind]
```

Gives:

```
    ['J', 'D', 'F']
    ['A', 'E', 'F']
    ['M', 'A', 'C']
    ['E', 'C', 'B']
    ['S', 'A', 'C']
```